# Should LC_ALL=C Always be used for Non-Locale-Specific sed Operations?

Tags: json, bash, sed, centos7

I have JSON files that are annotated with comments that I strip out before doing operations using `jq`. I just hit an interesting problem in which I received a JSON file with comment annotations that included some rich-text quote characters (hex 93 and hex 94). My existing sed dot `.` character did not match these characters. Here is a demonstration:

First, the input:

```
% echo -e '# \x93text\x94\n{"a":1}' | od -c
0000000   #     223   t   e   x   t 224  \n   {   "   a   "   :   1   }
0000020  \n
0000021
%
```

And here is the transform:

```
% echo -e '# \x93text\x94\n{"a":1}' | sed 's/^\s*#.*//' | od -c
0000000 223   t   e   x   t 224  \n   {   "   a   "   :   1   }  \n
0000017
%
```

Note that the dot character in the sed expression is not matching the hex 93 character. However, if I include `LC_ALL=C`:

```
% echo -e '# \x93text\x94\n{"a":1}' | LC_ALL=C sed 's/^\s*#.*//' | od -c
0000000  \n   {   "   a   "   :   1   }  \n
0000011
%
```

then the dot character in the sed expression does match the hex 93 and hex 94 characters. The sed documentation section [Locale Considerations](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Locale-Considerations) speaks of bracket expressions, but the behavior above seems to prove that this problem happens elsewhere.

It is interesting to note that deletion instead of substitution didn't show this problem:

```
% echo -e '# \x93text\x94\n{"a":1}' | sed '/^\s*#.*/d' | od -c         
0000000   {   "   a   "   :   1   }  \n
0000010
```

Given that I'm operating on annotated JSON files, I think the solution of adding `LC_ALL=C` to sed statements is reasonable.

**So, my question:** Is using `LC_ALL=C` something that I always want to use when doing non-locale-specific `sed` transformations (as would be applicable in annotated JSON files)? If not, what alternatives exist to avoid the problem I've shown above?

My environment:

- CentOS 7.3 [kernel-3.10.0-514.6.1.el7.x86_64]
- sed (GNU sed) 4.2.2 [sed-4.2.2-5.el7.x86_64]
- Bash 4.2.46(1) [bash-4.2.46-21.el7_3.x86_64]

Comment: not the problem under KSH (environment is cerftainly different) but trying your line  i get this that could help `echo -e '# \x93text\x94\n{"a":1}' |  sed '/^[[:space:]]*#.*/ s//[HERE]/' | od -c` give `0000000   [   H   E   R   E   ] 223   t   e   x   t 224  \n   {   "   a
0000020   "   :   1   }  \n
` so sed estimated in replacement that end of line is reached, not in selection

Comment: @NeronLeVelu yes, it's very odd behavior in any case. Since the sed webpage suggests including the `LC_ALL=C`, it leaves me wondering if this is a workaround for a bug in sed, or if it is a difficult-to-understand feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The C locale is a special locale that is meant to be the simplest locale. You could also say that while the other locales are for humans, the C locale is for computers. **In the C locale, characters are single bytes**, the charset is ASCII

On some systems, there's a difference with the POSIX locale where for instance the sort order for non-ASCII characters is not defined.

so LC_ALL=C is the secure way to take that non 8th bit character into account.

see comparaison

with LC, sed count as part of the character

```
echo -e '# \x93text\x94\n{"a":1}' | LC_ALL=C sed 's/[^[:alnum:]]/[HERE:&] /g' | od -c
0000000   [   H   E   R   E   :   #   ]       [   H   E   R   E   :
0000020   ]       [   H   E   R   E   : 223   ]       t   e   x   t   [
0000040   H   E   R   E   : 224   ]      \n   [   H   E   R   E   :   {
0000060   ]       [   H   E   R   E   :   "   ]       a   [   H   E   R
0000100   E   :   "   ]       [   H   E   R   E   :   :   ]       1   [
0000120   H   E   R   E   :   }   ]      \n
```

without LC, sed is not counted as part of the character to take into account (`[[:alnum:]]` and `[^[:alnum:]]` don't *see* 8th bit char)

```
 echo -e '# \x93text\x94\n{"a":1}' | sed 's/[[:alnum:]]/[HERE:&] /g' | od -c
0000000   #     223   [   H   E   R   E   :   t   ]       [   H   E   R
0000020   E   :   e   ]       [   H   E   R   E   :   x   ]       [   H
0000040   E   R   E   :   t   ]     224  \n   {   "   [   H   E   R   E
0000060   :   a   ]       "   :   [   H   E   R   E   :   1   ]       }
0000100  \n

echo -e '# \x93text\x94\n{"a":1}' | sed 's/[^[:alnum:]]/[HERE:&] /g' | od -c
0000000   [   H   E   R   E   :   #   ]       [   H   E   R   E   :
0000020   ]     223   t   e   x   t 224  \n   [   H   E   R   E   :   {
0000040   ]       [   H   E   R   E   :   "   ]       a   [   H   E   R
0000060   E   :   "   ]       [   H   E   R   E   :   :   ]       1   [
0000100   H   E   R   E   :   }   ]      \n
```

Comment: So, would you think that I might even use this as a global option in my scripts (`export LC_ALL=C`)? Even if string manipulation for other purposes involves locale-specific data, then I'm guessing that substitutions would still do the right thing. For example, a `s/$LOCALE_WORD/$REPLACEMENT/` where the two words are locale specific would still work correctly with `LC_ALL=C`, right? This would motivate me to set this as an environment variable instead of in from of each time I use sed. What do you think?

Comment: it's a sed behavior, so add it to sed only (every sed in your batch) to avoid other unexpected behavior on other app (just my point of view and way i use it in my batch when this issue could occur)

Comment: Very good. I'll do that.  Thanks for taking the time to answer. Marking this as the accepted answer.